# Multithreading with two infinite while functions

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, python-multithreading

I am working on a code which contains a while loop which always has the condition as True.
Is there some method by which i can initiate two threads and run them despite of the infinite loop present.?

```
##code
from threading import Thread
class myClass():
   def __init__():
      ##code here..
   def run(self):
      print 'Starting '
      while(True):
         print '1'
class myClassSecond():
   def __init_():
       ##code here
   def run(self):
       print 'starting second'
       while(True):
           print '2'


if __name__=='__main__':
   a=myClass()
   b=myClassSecond()
   aa=Thread(a.run())
   bb=Thread(b.run())
   aa.start()
   bb.start()
   aa.join()
```

On execution the Thread aa gets started but because of the while loop , aa won't exit from itself.and due to this Thread bb will not start.Is there any other approach with which i  can start these two thread.(P.S. while loop cannot be removed from code.)

OUTPUT:

```
1
1
1
1
1
 and so on.
```

Required output:
It should atleast give me somethin like :

1

2

kindof thing

Comment: Do you know that you can do `class MyClass(Thread): # code almost as before` and then you can do `a = MyClass(); a.start()`? The only thing to keep in mind is to add `super(MyClass, self).__init__()` in the `__init__` of your class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are never creating your threads... either of them.  You are processing the arguments of the first call to `Thread` and enter the infinite loop in `a.run()`.  You need to let `Thread` call run, not you.  Change the `run()` to `run` and set it as the `target`, like so:

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    a=myClass()
    b=myClassSecond()
    aa=Thread(target=a.run)
    bb=Thread(target=b.run)
    ...
```

Note: the first parameter of `Thread` is `group` which is not what you want.

Also you may want to consider making your threading object actually inherit from `Thread`.  Then you can simply do:

```
class myClass(Thread):
    def run(self):
        print 'Starting '
        while(True):
            print '1'

class myClassSecond(Thread):
    def run(self):
        print 'starting second'
        while(True):
            print '2'

if __name__=='__main__':
    a=myClass()
    b=myClassSecond()
    a.start()
    b.start()
    ...
```

Answer (score 4):

A good tutorial to reference for learning about concurrency (multi-threading) in python can be found at the following link.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm

I went and modified your provided code example to make it execute like you explained, keeping the code as similar as possible to your original example.

```
from threading import Thread

class myClass(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        print 'Starting'
        while True:
            print '1'

class myClassSecond(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        print 'Starting Second'
        while True:
            print '2'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = myClass()
    b = myClassSecond()

    a.start()
    b.start()
```

The output of this example follows below.

```
>>> 
Starting
>>> Starting Second

12

12

12

12

12

12

12

12

12

12

12

12

12

12
```

In the output you will notice that both threads output is printed to the same line, and that there is a blank line between each line of numbers. This happens because Standard Out (print function) is a shared resource. This means that each thread is competing for this resource. Each thread has access to standard out but the order is not guaranteed nor is it guaranteed that each thread will be able to finish executing its command before the other thread is given control of the CPU. Below is what is actually happening.

- Thread 1 output string: '1\n'
- Thread 2 output string: '2\n'

Notice the new line terminators. Normally when you print anything using the Print command in python the command will attempt to append '\n' to the end of the item if it can resulting in the next item printed displaying on a new line. With multi-threading the same thing is happening, but since standard out is a shared resource all of the text isn't getting added in the correct order.

The following list displays the order at which characters are being added to the display.

1. 1
2. 2
3. \n
4. \n

So the display would look as follows if the new line characters were visible.

```
12\n
\n
```

Hope this helps you better understand Threading, and helps you with your Threading problem as well.

-Andrew

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to invoke `join()`:

```
aa.start()
bb.start()
aa.join() # <--
```

Here is documentation link: https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join

Comment: On invoking join() i'm still getting the same previous output.Okay now i've edited the question.Please have a look